# Calculate Occurrence of String based on Group in R

Tags: r, count, data-manipulation

Here is my sample dataset.

```
Singer <- c("A","B","C","A","B","D")
Rank <- c(1,2,3,3,2,1)
data <- data_frame(Singer,Rank)
```

I would like to calculate the mean of rank for each singer. And I used the "summarise" function like below.

```
summarise(group_by(data,Singer),mean.rank = mean(Rank))
```

Here I want to add a column indicating how many times the singer show up. In this sample, "A" and "B" show up twice while "C" and "D" show up once.

I tried to use the "table(unlist())". But it did not work within the summarise function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dplyr solution

```
data
  Singer Rank
1      A    1
2      B    2
3      C    3
4      A    3
5      B    2
6      D    1
library(tidyverse)
data %>% group_by(Singer) %>% summarize(mean_rank=mean(Rank),count=n())
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Singer mean_rank count
  <fctr>     <dbl> <int>
1      A         2     2
2      B         2     2
3      C         3     1
4      D         1     1
```

Comment: Excellent. If it was correct, please choose it as the best answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

A data.table solution

```
   library(data.table)
   setDT(data)[, list(mean_rank = mean(Rank), count = .N), by = 'Singer']
```